# How to Aggregate Strings Using Google Sheets Pivot Table Calculated Field

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets, pivot-table, calculated-field

I have a Google spreadsheet in which I recorded text evaluations of various teams made by individuals. The sheet, named Data, looks like this

```
    Col A   Col B  Col C
     Rater | Team | Feedback
  -------------------------
r1   Jim   | A    | Great
r2   Jane  | A    | Sucks
r3   Kate  | A    | Fabulous
r4   Jim   | B    | Mhm
r5   Jane  | B    | Wow
r6   Kate  | B    | Lousy
```

I am using the pivot table "Calculated field" option to generate a new table with an aggregation of the feedback for each team like this

```
Team | Feedback
A    | Great, Sucks, Fabulous
B    | Mhm, Wow, Lousy
```

I choose Column B as the option for Rows and for values I use a "calculated field" with the custom the formula CONCATENATE=('Data'!C:C). In Column Feedback I get all the entries for column C for all the teams, like this

```
Team | Feedback
A    | Great, Sucks, Fabulous, Mhm, Wow, Lousy
B    | Great, Sucks, Fabulous, Mhm, Wow, Lousy
```

How do I  modify the Calculated Field formula to separate that feedback by team?

Comment: why you are tagging `excel-formula`?

Comment: Should work the same for both, right? The formula, I mean... I can delete it of course, but I thought the more eyes, the better.

Comment: There are many spreadsheet function that work the same way on Excel and Google Sheets there are many other that don't. I'm not sure if this is the case for calculated fields on pivot tables. By the other hand, the formula `CONCATENATE=('Data'!C:C)` is wrong. Do you mean ` `=CONCATENATE('Data'!C:C)`?

Comment: yes, I made a typo, it should be =CONCATENATE('Data'!C:C)